# Select a class field by name as though it were a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a function that filters objects of a specific class by a chosen field. The way I currently do this is that I pass a string naming the field as an argument to the function. Ideally I would want to be able to use this string to select the field in the object, similar to a dictionary (this functionality exists in javascript for example).

So I have the function (cut down to the relevant bits) here:

```
private List<HangingArtBundle> ConstrainBundlesBy(List<HangingArtBundle> bundles, string valueString, string constraint)
{
    List<HangingArtBundle> retBundles = new List<HangingArtBundle>();
    List<string> values = new List<string>(valueString.Split(new char[] { '|' }));

    foreach (HangingArtBundle bundle in bundles)
    {
        if (values.Contains(ConstrainedField(constraint, bundle)))
        {
            retBundles.Add(bundle);
        }
    }

    return retBundles;
}
```

I would like to be able to replace the `ConstrainedField(constraint, bundle)` part with something like `bundle[constraint]`, where `constraint` is the name of a field of the class `HangingArtBundle`. Instead, I have to use this function below, which requires me to manually add field names as needed:

```
private string ConstrainedField(string field, HangingArtBundle bundle)
{
    if (field.Equals("Category"))
    {
        return bundle.Category;
    }
    else if (field.Equals("AUToolTab"))
    {
        return bundle.AUToolTab;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

If it helps at all, here is the class (essentially just a struct):

```
public class HangingArtBundle
{
    public string CP { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string AUToolTab { get; set; }
    public List<HangingArtEntry> Art { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible to do in an elegant way in C#?

Comment: Reflection may be an obvious answer here, but I'm more concerned with what this code is actually trying to accomplish. It doesn't seem like you really need Reflection or meta programming constructs. Seems more like you're trying to filter a collection of objects whose properties have some particular value. If this is the case, my suggestion would be to refactor this into clearer code, instead of trying to pull off some bizarre code using reflection. just my two cents

Comment: @ErOx Well, I have a cache of these HangingArtBundles that is accessible by an API, which has methods like "GetAllHangingArtByCategory" and "GetAllHangingArtByAUToolTab", whose bodies were identical besides the filtering field. So I wrote a generic version of the GetAllHangingArtByX function, which brought me to this question. I suppose one cleaner fix would be to change the format that my data is stored in, but I chose this struct-like setup to most cleanly emulate a nested JSON structure - which these results will ultimately be serialized to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `System.Reflection` for this

```
 private string GetField(HangingArtBundle hab, string property)
 {
    return (string)hab.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(hab, null);
 }
```

[image]

Or perhaps an Extension method to make life a bit easier:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string GetField(this HangingArtBundle hab, string property)
        {
            if (hab.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p => p.Name.Equals(property)))
            {
                return (string)hab.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(hab, null);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
  string result = bundle.GetField("CP");
```

Comment: added a extension method example incase this is easier for you. :)